# Why the image is blurry on 4K display if I set 1920*1080 resolution?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, 4k-resolution

I have 2 27'' displays: 4K and FullHD native resolutions.
If I set 1920*1080 on the 4K display, the image looks blurry in comparison with FullHD native display.

I would not be surprised with any other resolutions, because I understand that pixels are physical squares, so if a ratio between 2 numbers is not a whole number, we could see artifacts.

But in this particular case FullHD is exactly 2 times smaller than 4K on each dimention. So each dot in 1920*1080 image should take exactly 4 physical pixels on 4K display and I do not see any reason for blur.

So why the blurriness appears?

Comment: Pure guess - antialiasing is being handled differently?

Comment: I asked "why", not "how to solve", but It seems like I found some ugly, but working solution. My display has D-Sub input and also it has a possibility to switch HDMI mode from 2.0 to 1.4. The both cases support only 1920*1080@60Hz, so If I plug the display using D-Sub or using HDMI 1.4, the video adapter counts FullHD as a native resolution and outputs image without upscaling blur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has a long history. You may see an NVIDIA feature request dating
from the year 2012 at
[Nonblurry Upscaling at Integer Ratios](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/844905/geforce-drivers/-feature-request-nonblurry-upscaling-at-integer-ratios/),
still today without any answer or solution.

In short: The video adapter uses a more sophisticated algorithm than simple
pixel multiplication (two pixels for one), which works well for many tasks
but not very good for this too-simple task.

Most advice you will find for the problem would be to replace the display adapter
and/or monitor, which is not very practical.

One person has [claimed](https://johnstechpages.com/node/11) success in this
task. I quote below part of his advice (with small modifications):

> You have to convince Windows that your display supports HD as a native
>   resolution.  This can easily be done by using CRU (Custom Resolution
>   Utility) authored by ToastyX and can be found here:
>
> https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU
>
> It was as simple as adding 1920x1080, rebooting, and selecting that
>   resolution.  I added it to detailed and standard resolutions and all
>   is well in that department.

I have not tried this solution and so cannot vouch that it works.

Comment: this solution does not work for me, but I asked "why", not "how to solve the problem", so your answer is good:)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I spent hours on this issue today, and finally find a solution that worked for me, so I wanted to share.
For me, the solution was to go in the NVIDIA Control Panel, select the blurry screen, use NVIDIA Color settings and select : "Output color depth: 10 bpc" (the default was 8).

I has been a life changer, my screen is sharp again.